# find $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{100,000,001}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find $100^{101}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{100,000,001}$.

What I have done is

$100^4 = 100,000,000 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{100,000,001}$ (Fermat's Theorem).

So $100^{101} = 100^{25+ 4+ 1} = 1+100 = 101$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{100,000,001}$.

Is that correct?

Comment: `100^4 = ...` Recheck your signs. `So 100^101 = ...` Recheck your `+` vs. `*` operators.

Comment: Deleting a question after having received an answer is not a fair use of MSE.

Answer (score 3):

$$100^4 = 10^8 \equiv -1 \pmod{10^8+1}$$
$$100^{101}=100^{4\times 25+1}=100(100^4)^{25}\equiv -100 \pmod{10^8+1}$$

Comment: I think 100^4 = 108 ≡ 1 (mod 108 + 1)

Comment: Let's work with smaller number, which of the statement is true a) $2 \equiv 1 \pmod{2+1}$ or b) $2 \equiv -1 \pmod{2+1}$.

Comment: Ferma' Theorem is if p is prime, a ≠ 0 in Zp, then a ^(p-1) = 1 in Zp

Comment: but we are not working with $a^{10^8+1-1}$ right? We are dealing with $a^8$.

Comment: but p = 10^8 + 1, a = 10, so p-1 = 10^8

Comment: if $p$ is prime (I didnt' verify that), then $10^{10^8} \equiv 1 \pmod{10^8+1}$. $10^8$ and $10^{10^8}$ are not the same isn't it?

Comment: You're correct. Thank you so much for explaining this to me!